# VB.NET compatibility issue between versions 4.0 and 4.5

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-4.0, .net-4.5, ftdi

I'm writing a program on VB.NET, using a WIN8, 64-bit computer. I have the .NET 4.5 framework installed.

I'm having a hard time running the program on a WINXP 32-bit computer, which has the .NET 4.0 framework.

I tried running the .EXE file from the bin folder, but it says it's not a valid win32 application.

I tried to publish the program and install it on the other computer, but that didn't work as well.

I also tried to change the framework under Project -> Properties -> application tab.

nothing worked. 
Does anybody have an idea how I should run the program on the other computer?

Changing the framework also caused my application problems while working with the driver for an FTDI chip ( http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm ).
Any ideas about that? the FTDI website doesn't have different DLLs for different windows versions

I would appreciate any suggestions,
Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: Change the Solution Properties --> Configuration Properties to Active(Any CPU) and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure of two things in the properties of your project:

1. Application -> Target framework: This has to be .NET Framework 4, not .NET Framework 4.5
2. Platform target: This has to be x86 or (better) Any CPU. It must not be x64.

Comment: Thank you. It was also necessary to uncheck the .NET4.5 from publish --> perquisites.

Comment: Everything worked only when I used the .NET 3.5 framework rather than the 4.0, no idea why.

Comment: @EyalD: Maybe because the Windows XP computer only has the "Client Profile" of .NET 4 installed.